# Fade an image out (down-arrow) when a user scrolls 100px or so down my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The arrow image currently sits at the bottom of the screen using css. The I have the image on the screen using

```
<img class="down-arrow" src="pathtoimg"/>
```

The button is a down arrow in white with a black circle around it with the opacity set to 40%. I would like to have it own my homescreen to inform visitors to scroll down. When they scroll down I would like for it to fade away. I want it on the bottom of the screen no matter the size of monitor a user is viewing it on. How should I do this? I am running wordpress and beaver builder. Not really familiar with jquery/javascript.

(Edit: I also have made the button so when you click on it, it brings you down to a pre-determined place on the page. It links using:

```
<a href="locationtojumpto"><img "codestuffhere"/></a>
```

)

Here is the css I used to keep the image centered and at the bottom of my site:

```
.down-arrow { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 50%; }
```

and I tried some jquery from another page, but I do not know how to incorporate it into the site. I am using beaver builder and I tried going to tools then layout css/ javascript and put it in there under javascript, but it did not work. I also wouldn't mind the image fading when it disappears after the user scrolls 100px.

This is the jQuery I used but I honestly do not know hot it works or how to use it or where to put it or anything.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -
 $(window).scrollTop() / 100);
  });
```

I put it in beaver builder tools under javascript but I do not think it goes there and also have no idea how to get it to run on the image. I am an extreme beginner here, cut me some slack. :(

Answer (score 1):

I've created this pen as an example.  Enjoy.

http://codepen.io/StevenVentimiglia/pen/PzQPxV

HTML

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <button class="btn">This is a button.</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #999;
}

#mainContainer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 2400px;
    background: #eee;
}
#mainContainer button.btn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

JS

```
// Scroll Control
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
    $('.btn').hide();
} else {
    $('.btn').show();
}
});
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') || location.hostname === this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Could I replace .btn with .down-arrow?

Comment: Here is where you can see how the javascript tool works. This is where I put the code: [link] (https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/knowledge-base/global-and-layout-settings/)

Comment: You can replace '.btn' with '.down-arrow'.  If it's an image, then it should have the '.down-arrow' class.  The best way to learn how to fix and customize HTML/CSS/JS for websites would be to learn how to write it from scratch.  Otherwise, you'll need to learn the UI you're using.

Comment: I think the issue was I am not loading jQuery lol talked to my host and they said they will enable it within 20 minutes. Thanks so much for the help! My code is working and I think I will go for it as it actually fades the image instead of disappears, however I am extremely appreciative of your efforts. :)